# Odoo 13 : How to use message_post() to send message in the chatter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I want to send message via the chatter in odoo 13. I use the method message_post() but it doesn't appears nor in the chatter nor in the Discuss application (like normal chat sended by users or odoo bot). 
Strangly, the message is created when I checked it Settings > Technical > Messages.
Here is my code :

```
                    try:
                        employee.message_post(
                        subject=(_("Timesheet reminder")),
                        body="Nous vous informons que vous n'avez pas complété votre feuille de temps du %s" % (yesterday.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')),
                        message_type='comment',
                        subtype='mail.mt_comment',
                    )
                    except Exception as e:
                        _logger.critical(e)
```

employee is a model of type "hr.employee".
Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I could handle it. The system need to use mail.channel instead of mail.message. Here is the code :

```
# sending message
try:
    channel_odoo_bot_users = '%s, %s' % (odoo_bot.name, employee.user_id.name)
    channel_obj = self.env['mail.channel']
    channel_id = channel_obj.search([('name', 'like', channel_odoo_bot_users)])
    if not channel_id:
        channel_id = channel_obj.create({
            'name': channel_odoo_bot_users,
            'email_send': False,
            'channel_type': 'chat',
            'public': 'private',
            'channel_partner_ids': [(4, odoo_bot.partner_id.id), (4, employee.user_id.partner_id.id)]
        })
    channel_id.message_post(
        subject="Timesheet reminder",
        body="Nous vous informons que vous n'avez pas complété votre feuille de temps du %s" % (yesterday.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')),
        message_type='comment',
        subtype='mail.mt_comment',
       )
except Exception as e:
    _logger.critical(e)
```